# A Story in the Sea Shanty?

Tags: riddle, word, word-problem

A bottle washed ashore this morning and I found a note inside.  This seems like it may just be a sea shanty, but I feel there is meaning in the words, and I'd like to know what inspired it.

> A crew of seven, we set out, the driving wind a chill
>   Losing our captain, no one pouts, but all have fallen ill
>
> Another gone, we look to the cook- organize us, set us straight
>   And yet another, cries first mate, but alas, his loss will fill our plate
>
> Three remaining- *Is it raining?*- We drown ourselves with a drink
>   We leave outside, we two, we hide, though the craft begins to sink
>
> Afloat atop the wreckage, their story lies with only one
>   If those clouds should block the sun, the story may be told by none

Can you determine the inspiration for each line, or what the lines are truly describing?

**For clarification:** There is something unique to take away from each line, one line possibly helping you find what to take away from the next.  The accepted answer should have each line represented and explained.

*Another bottle may wash up on shore, if the winds aren't blowing in the right direction.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe @Kate is on the right track, and that the answer is indeed:

> a seven letter word, which has letters removed each line.

Specifically:

> SAILING - "set out [in a] driving wind"
>  AILING - "all have fallen ill"
>  ALIGN - "set us straight"
>  GAIN - "his loss [is our gain]"
>  GIN - "drown ourselves with a drink"
>  IN - "leave outside, ... we hide"
>  I - "the story lies with only one"

Of course that leaves the last line "unexplained", but presumably that just means:

> none of the crew survived, since following the pattern would necessarily make the last line nothing at all... But if that's true, who sent the message in the bottle?

Comment: I think you're right!

Comment: You got it! Nice job working it down the line, and yes, following all the way leaves no crew members.  I wasn't there, but I would have to assume that the message was written before it became clear whether or not the sun would be blocked by yet another storm.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a

> seven letter word from which letters are removed

The last four I think are

> dine, din, in, I

Need to add more till I get back to the beginning. Then I will connect to clues (I know them, just don't want to type them if this is all wrong)

Comment: You definitely figured out what was going on, but as you've noted, Alconja nailed it.  Also, I love the word din and would give the +1 even if that's all your answer comprised of.